# How can i get inserted record id from dynamic table namename and output that id

Tags: post, stored-procedures, dynamic, output, return-value

```
ALTER PROC Experience
  @Subject1 INT
 ,@Subject2 INT
 ,@TableNumber INT
 ,@IDR INT OUTPUT
  AS
  BEGIN
  DECLARE @CMDS VARCHAR(MAX);           
        DECLARE @Subj1 VARCHAR(10);
        SET @Subj1=CONVERT(varchar(10),@Subject1);
        DECLARE @Subj2 VARCHAR(10);
        SET @Subj2=CONVERT(varchar(10),@Subject2);       
        DECLARE @TableNames VARCHAR(100);       
        SET @TableNames='TableNo_'+CONVERT(varchar(50),@TableNumber);          
        SET @CMDS='INSERT INTO '+@TableNames+' (@Subject1,@Subject1) VALUES('''+@Subj1+''','''+@Subj2+''');'
        EXEC (@CMDS);
  SELECT @IDR =  SCOPE_IDENTITY();  
  END
```

inserting is not problem  it is working but i can not get last inseted id and i can not post it as output.i am using mssql and stored procedure(SELECT @IDR =  SCOPE_IDENTITY()  and output this value)

Comment: Have you try to print out the content of `@CMDS` for debugging ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Experience
  @Subject1 INT,
  @Subject2 INT,
  @TableNumber INT,
  @IDR INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @CMDS NVARCHAR(MAX);
  DECLARE @Subj1 NVARCHAR(10), @Subj2 NVARCHAR(10), @TableNames NVARCHAR(100);

  SET @Subj1 = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @Subject1);
  SET @Subj2 = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @Subject2);
  SET @TableNames = N'TableNo_' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @TableNumber);

  SET @CMDS = N'INSERT INTO ' + @TableNames + ' (Subject1, Subject2) VALUES (' + @Subj1 + ',' + @Subj2 + '); 
                SELECT @IDR = SCOPE_IDENTITY();';

  EXEC sp_executesql @CMDS, N'@IDR INT OUTPUT', @IDR OUTPUT;

  -- Output the ID for the caller
  SELECT @IDR;
END
```